# order of a permutation and lexicographic order

Tags: order-theory, permutations

Let $M$ be an $n\times m$ matrix, say with entries in  $\left\{0,1\right\}$ ; and  let $\mathcal C(M)$ be the $n\times m$ matrix such that there exists $P$, $m\times m$ permutation  matrix such that $M.P=\mathcal C(M)$ and such that the columns of $\mathcal C(M)$ are *lexicographically increasing* (1) (for a formal definition of (1) see [reflexive relations that are "tridiagonally cycle-indexed" (or "almost ordered" matrices/relations)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298321/reflexive-relations-that-are-tridiagonally-cycle-indexed-or-almost-ordered))
$\mathcal R(M):= \mathcal C(M^t))^t$ is the matrix you get from $M$ that rows are lexicographically increasing.

We now say that $\mathcal L=\mathcal C\,o\,\mathcal R$.

Let $Q$ be a $m\times m$ permutation matrix s.t. $Q^q=Id$. We  define $\mathcal L_Q$ to be such that $\mathcal L_Q(M)=\mathcal L(M).Q$ for all $M$ of size $n\times m$.

> Does there exists $r\in \mathbb N$ such that $\mathcal L_Q^{r+iq}(M)=\mathcal L_Q^r(M)$ for any  $i\in \mathbb N$

The cases that seem the most interesting to me are $\mathcal L_{Id}=\mathcal L$ and $\mathcal L_J$ where $J$ is the $i\mapsto m-i$ permutation matrix, I talked about these cases in the upper link.

---

Example with $m=n=4$

$Q=J=\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\ 1& 0 & 0 & 0  
\end{matrix}$

(so $q=2$)

Let's take
 $M=\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1  \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0  \\ 1& 1 & 1 & 0  
\end{matrix}$

We range rows according to lexicographic order :

$\mathcal R(M)=\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0  \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1    \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 0  
\end{matrix}$

And now columns...
$\mathcal L(M)=\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1  \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 1  
\end{matrix}$

And we multiply on the right by $J$:

$\mathcal L_J(M)= \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1  \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1  
\end{matrix}$

If we apply $\mathcal L_J$ to $\mathcal L_J(M)$ we then get :

$\mathcal L^2_J(M)= \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1  \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0  
\end{matrix}$

etc....

We will get :

$\mathcal L^4_J(M)=\mathcal L^6_J(M)=\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1  
\end{matrix}$

We could verify that $\mathcal  L^3_J(M)\ne \mathcal L^5_J(M)(\ne L^4_J(M))$ and then $r=4$ is the smallest possible (and $k$ such that $i\mapsto L^{r+i}_J(M)$ is $2$-periodic but not constant)

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding the question, because it seems to me that $r=1$ would work. Could you give me an example where $r$ can't just be $1$? I hope that such an example will clear up my confusion.

Comment: I'm sorry I completely forgot a step in my construction (the composing with transposition part (that occurs in the link) is missing!!) I 'm editing write now!!

Comment: @Andreas Blass : Thank you very much and sorry for the wasted time! I edited , and I think I corrected all typos, I also fixed an example, to avoid misunderstanding from any typos or blunder  I did't see

Comment: It "seems" like it is also working for arbitrary $Q\in M_m(F_2)$ such that $Q^q=Iq$, and maybe we can have a nice generalization to any field and even to any ring ! (after deciding an arbitrary total order on the ring so that you can define a lexicographic order on rows/columns)

Comment: I posted a new question with general $Q\in GL_m(F_2)$ such that $Q^q=Id$  here : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306673/root-of-identity-matrix-and-lexicographic-order

Comment: I brute-force went through all binary matrices with $n=m\le6$, and it happens to holds for $Q=Id$ and $Q=J$ on those small sizes. It doesn't hold for many $Q$'s however. I'll list those for which it holds.

Comment: That's great, and very usefull! And I'm sure the list will teach us something!

Comment: I thing the case $Q=Id$ is true. We first notice that in the cycle there should appear a column (seen like the characteristic fonction of a set) that is a minimum for inclusion, and then it will state at the first place all the time. We do the same statement with the bloc of rows that begin by $0$ and those that begin by $1$, and so on... (dont have place to be very precise and formal^^)

Comment: Great, I understand your explanation about $Id$. In other words : the first column never increases as a binary number, so it is going to stay the same at some point, as two blocks of $00\ldots0$ and $11\dots1$. At that point the same holds for the 2nd column for each sublock, and so on.

Comment: Now get ready for a shock. There is no such general truth for $Q=J$ and period $2$. For a few $6\times 7$ binary matrices, the period is $4$. For a few others, it is $6$. Some others, $3$. I'll show you those counterexamples in an answer. I'll also explore random big matrices to see better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are counterexamples for $Q=J$.

Here is a binary $6\times7$ binary matrix $M$ that belongs to an orbit of $\mathcal{L}_J$ with period $3$:

$\begin{matrix}
1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&1&0&1\\
1&0&0&1&0&1&1\\
0&1&0&0&1&1&1\\
\end{matrix}$

Here is another with period $4$:

$\begin{matrix}
1&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&1&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&0&1&1\\
1&0&0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&1&0\\
\end{matrix}$

and another with period $6$:

$\begin{matrix}
1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0&0&1&1\\
0&1&0&0&0&1&1\\
\end{matrix}$

On the whole set of $7\times 7$ binary matrices, $\mathcal{L}_J$ gets
$$
\begin{array}{r l}
     326\,166&\text{fixed matrices}\\
 86\,146\,036&\text{distinct orbits of length }2\\
           94&\text{distinct orbits of length }3\\
       5\,400&\text{distinct orbits of length }4\\
            8&\text{distinct orbits of length }5\\
          196&\text{distinct orbits of length }6\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: What a great  precious ( and chocking!)  information. I'm going to check if I have a proof of the statement for $Q=J$ and $M$ is the adjacency matrix of a partial order... because I did the "sketch"  in my mind a bit quickly,especially to the light of the counterexamples that you found!!