# root of identity matrix and lexicographic order

Tags: linear-algebra, order-theory, permutations

I asked a question here [order of a permutation and lexicographic order](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306572/order-of-a-permutation-and-lexicographic-order) but it seems*** that a very powerful and rich generalization  can be made!

Let $A$ be a finite ring together with an arbitrary **total order** $<^*$ and let  $L: M_n(A)\to M_n(A)$ be the application that sorts  the rows of a matrix according to the (increasing) lexicographic order (induced by $<^*$) and the columns of the matrice we get, according to the  increasing lexicographic order (increasingly too). We then define $L_Q(M):=L(M).Q$ for any $Q\in M_n(A)$.

> Suppose that $Q^q=Id$ for some $q\in \mathbb N$ and $Q\in GL_n(A)$. Is is true that for any $M\in M_n(A)$, there exists $r\in \mathbb N$ such that for any $i\in \mathbb N$, we have $L_Q^r(M)=L_Q^{r+iq}(M)$ ?

[edit : it is not true for $A=\mathbb Z$, but it seems asymptotically true up to a scalar multiplication of matrices, anyway I edited and ask $A$ to be finite]

Comment: This question makes me think of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131373/smith-normal-form-of-powers-of-a-matrix. Is there any link?

Comment: @Chris Birkbeck : I'm not sure to see one yet, but maybe. Also, I don't understand all the notations. Is $*$ the usual product in the question you mentioned ? or something else?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure * is the usual product. It just reminded me of this, since in a way SNF is looking for the smallest entries on each row, but this is probably too vague to be of any use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating $\mathsf L_Q$ over an initial matrix shall always yield a periodic sequence at some point because there is only finitely many possible matrices, but the period is not necessarily $q$ or a multiple or divisor of $q$.

Here is an example where the period is $4$ while $q=3$. It is a modification of [yours](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306572/order-of-a-permutation-and-lexicographic-order) where now $Q$ permutes the 3 first columns.

$Q=
\;\;\begin{matrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{matrix}\;\; $
and 
$\;M=
\;\;\begin{matrix}0&0&1&1\\1&0&0&1\\0&1&1&0\\1&1&1&0\end{matrix}\;\;$

$ $

$ \xrightarrow{\mathsf R}
\;\;\begin{matrix}0&0&1&1\\0&1&1&0\\1&0&0&1\\1&1&1&0\end{matrix}\;\; \xrightarrow{\mathsf C}
\;\;\begin{matrix}0&0&1&1\\0&1&0&1\\1&0&1&0\\1&1&0&1\end{matrix}\;\; \xrightarrow{\mathsf Q} \color{red}{
\;\;\begin{matrix}1&0&0&1\\0&0&1&1\\1&1&0&0\\0&1&1&1\end{matrix}\;\; }
$

$ $

$ \xrightarrow{\mathsf R}
\;\;\begin{matrix}0&0&1&1\\0&1&1&1\\1&0&0&1\\1&1&0&0\end{matrix}\;\; \xrightarrow{\mathsf C}
\;\;\begin{matrix}0&0&1&1\\0&1&1&1\\1&0&0&1\\1&1&0&0\end{matrix}\;\; \xrightarrow{\mathsf Q}
\;\;\begin{matrix}1&0&0&1\\1&0&1&1\\0&1&0&1\\0&1&1&0\end{matrix}\;\; 
$

$ $

$ \xrightarrow{\mathsf R}
\;\;\begin{matrix}0&1&0&1\\0&1&1&0\\1&0&0&1\\1&0&1&1\end{matrix}\;\; \xrightarrow{\mathsf C}
\;\;\begin{matrix}0&0&1&1\\0&1&0&1\\1&0&1&0\\1&1&1&0\end{matrix}\;\; \xrightarrow{\mathsf Q}
\;\;\begin{matrix}1&0&0&1\\0&0&1&1\\1&1&0&0\\1&1&1&0\end{matrix}\;\; 
$

$ $

$ \xrightarrow{\mathsf R}
\;\;\begin{matrix}0&0&1&1\\1&0&0&1\\1&1&0&0\\1&1&1&0\end{matrix}\;\; \xrightarrow{\mathsf C}
\;\;\begin{matrix}0&0&1&1\\0&1&0&1\\1&1&0&0\\1&1&1&0\end{matrix}\;\; \xrightarrow{\mathsf Q}
\;\;\begin{matrix}1&0&0&1\\0&0&1&1\\0&1&1&0\\1&1&1&0\end{matrix}\;\; 
$

$ $

$ \xrightarrow{\mathsf R}
\;\;\begin{matrix}0&0&1&1\\0&1&1&0\\1&0&0&1\\1&1&1&0\end{matrix}\;\; \xrightarrow{\mathsf C}
\;\;\begin{matrix}0&0&1&1\\0&1&0&1\\1&0&1&0\\1&1&0&1\end{matrix}\;\; \xrightarrow{\mathsf Q} \color{red}{
\;\;\begin{matrix}1&0&0&1\\0&0&1&1\\1&1&0&0\\0&1&1&1\end{matrix}\;\; }
$

Comment: Thank you very much, this is more than I expected because I was kind of convinced that the statement was true if $Q$ is a permutation matrix. I think the result is true if $Q$ is the $n\times n$ matrix associated to $i\mapsto n-i$, but I only showed this if $M$ is an "order matrix"... Thank you again for this great answer. I'm kind of relieved that the statement is wrong because, I was quite annoyed by not being able to prove it^^

Comment: You are welcome. This is interesting. I'll investigate the case $n-i$ with a computer search. What do you mean by "order matrix"? The adjacency matrix of a partially ordered set?

Comment: :Yes it is what I mean, sorry for the unusual terminology!